# How to read data from SOAP header in client side

Tags: php, soap-client

I have SOAP response which looks like

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Header>
        <AuthorizationToken soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <Token>5c31cca8-8303-4d01-a564-a99569a0963a</Token>
        </AuthorizationToken>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <AuthenticateResponse>
            <AuthenticateResult>http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/</AuthenticateResult>
        </AuthenticateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and no clue how to read data from the header (get a token value). I'm using `SoapClient` from PHP5.

Answer (score 2):

From http://drupalcode.org/project/netforum.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/xwebSecureOD.class.inc it looks like this should work:

```
$soapclient->__soapCall($fname, $arguments, null, $this->getAuthHeaders(), $responseHeaders);
$responseHeaders['AuthorizationToken']->Token;
```

That link has a class that extends PHP's soap object and does some caching and drupal specific things, but you should be able to remove those pieces and be left with a new class that transparently handles the sliding authorization token netFORUM uses.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php):

```
$soapclient->__soapCall("soapmethod", array(parameters), null, $input_headers, &$output_headers);
```

$output_headers should then contain the headers from the response message.

Comment: Somehow I can't get it to work. Also I have try to parse SOAP response with SimpleXML using code below but same results - can't get token value.   $res = $client->__getLastResponse();
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($res,NULL,NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
  $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

Comment: foreach($xml->xpath('AuthorizationToken') as $header)
 {
     var_export($header->xpath('Token')); 
 }

Comment: I have got to work SimpleXML and code below:                         $res = $client->__getLastResponse();
  $xmlString = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $res);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
  $token = $xml->soapHeader[0]->AuthorizationToken[0]->Token;

Answer (score 0):

I got this from JackTheKnife on http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1651481

```
    $result = $service->getLastResponse();
    $xmlString = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $result);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
    $token = $xml->soapHeader[0]->AuthorizationToken[0]->Token;
```