# PHP SoapClient and creating header

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to create custom header using PHP SOAP CLient which will looks like

```
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizationToken xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <Token>string</Token>
    </AuthorizationToken>   </soap:Header>
```

My code looks like:

```
      $client = new SoapClient("http://nftpsandbox.avectra.com/xweb/netFORUMXMLONDemand.asmx?WSDL",array("trace" => 1));

    try {

        $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/', 'AuthorizationToken', $token, false);
        $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));              

        $result = $client->CheckEWebUser(array('szEmail' => $userName , 'szPassword' => $password));

    }
    catch (SoapFault $result)
    {
        echo $result->faultstring;
    }   

    catch   (Exception $result){
    }
```

But Request header which I'm getting looks like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns1:AuthorizationToken>
     <ns1:Token></ns1:Token>
  </ns1:AuthorizationToken>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Any idea why node Token is empty when `$token` has a value?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` on `$token` before creating soapheader?

Comment: var_dump result: object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { [0]=> string(36) "beec45e3-fd5d-418f-a9a6-60566f010eec" }

Comment: Also when I switch code to    $auth = array('ns1:Token'=>$token);
   $authvar = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
   $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/', 'AuthorizationToken', $authvar, false);
   $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));    I'm getting token value but as BOGUS tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleXMLLement can be to hard to handle, try passing simple instance of stdClass

```
$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->Token = '123';

$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/', 'AuthorizationToken', $auth, false);
```

Comment: Great. Got it to work. BTW is there any way to retrieve token from the header (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124861/how-to-read-data-from-soap-header-in-client-side).